# React-Native Big Problems with Confirming Password

Tags: reactjs, react-native, passwords, native-base

i got a Questions because I am new in React native! I was trying to find an Answer that fits with my Code. But nothing is working well! Im overloaded. Maybe some of u guys can help me with my problem!

So i need a "simple" confirming password message if someone is writing the two fields wrong because there is no match!

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View, Image, TextInput} from 'react-native';
import { Container, Header, Content, Button, Icon, Body, Left, Right,
    Text, Title, Card, CardItem } from 'native-base';
import styles from '../Style/Style.js'
import Foect from 'foect';
import IconNew from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';

export default class AnmeldeScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
        icEye: 'visibility-off',
        password: true,
    }
}

static navigationOptions = {
  header: null
}
changePwdType = () => {
  let newState;
  if (this.state.password) {
      newState = {
          icEye: 'visibility',
          password: false
      }
  } else {
      newState = {
          icEye: 'visibility-off',
          password: true
      }
  }

  // set new state value
  this.setState(newState)

};

  render () {
    var {navigate} = this.props.navigation;

    return (
          <Container>
{/*---------------------------------------------------- H E A D E R  ------------------------------------------------------------*/}

                        <Header>
                        <Left>
                        <Button transparent onPress={() => navigate("Start", {})}>
                        <Icon name="arrow-back" />
                        </Button>
                        </Left>                        
                        <Body>
                        <Title style={styles.titelintervall}>Registrieren</Title>
                        </Body>
                        <Right>
                        </Right>
                        </Header>     
{/*---------------------------------------------------- C O N T E N T ------------------------------------------------------------*/}
         <Content padder>
         
            <Image source={require('../images/low-carb-camp-logo-breit.png')} style={styles.secondimagelogo} />
            <Foect.Form
  defaultValue={{
    email: ''
  }}
  onValidSubmit={model => {
    console.log(model);
  }}
>
  { /* you can use form for triggering submit or checking form state(form.isSubmitted, form.isValid, ...) */ }
  { form => (
    <View>
      { /* every Foect.Control must have a name and optionally validation rules */ }
      <Foect.Control name="fullName" required minLength={2} maxLength={32}>
        { /* you can use control for getting/setting it's value, checking/updating(control.isValid, control.markAsTouched(), ...) it's state, checking it's errors(control.errors.required) */ }
        { control => (
          <View>
            <Text style={{ marginTop: 10, color: '#8BC051' }}>Dein Name</Text>

            <TextInput
              style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderBottomWidth: 1}}
              /* mark control as touched on blur */ 
              onBlur={control.markAsTouched}
              /* update control's value */ 
              onChangeText={(text) => control.onChange(text)}
               /* get control's value */ 
              value={control.value}
              placeholder="Hier vollständigen Namen eingeben"
            />

            { /* check control state and show error if necessary */ }
            { control.isTouched &&
              control.isInvalid && 
              <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>Bitte trage deinen Namen ein.</Text> }
          </View>
        ) }
      </Foect.Control>


      <Foect.Control name="email" required email>
        { control => (
          <View>
            <Text style={{ marginTop: 10, color: '#8BC051' }}>Email</Text>

            <TextInput
              style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderBottomWidth: 1}}
              keyboardType="email-address"
              onBlur={control.markAsTouched}
              onChangeText={(text) => control.onChange(text)}
              value={control.value}
              placeholder="Hier E-Mail eingeben"
            />

            { control.isTouched &&
              control.isInvalid && 
              <View>
                <Text style={{ color: 'red'}}>{control.value} ist keine gültige E-Mail</Text>
              </View> }
          </View>
        ) }
      </Foect.Control>


      <Foect.Control name="password" required pattern={/(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$/}>
        { control => (
          <View>
            <Text style={{ marginTop: 10, color: '#8BC051' }}>Passwort
            </Text>

            <TextInput
              style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderBottomWidth: 1}}
              secureTextEntry={true}
              onBlur={control.markAsTouched}
              onChangeText={(text) => control.onChange(text)}
              value={control.value}
              secureTextEntry={this.state.password}
              placeholder="Passwort erstellen"
            />
<IconNew style={styles.icon}
                      name={this.state.icEye}
                      size={25}
                      color={this.props.iconColor}
                      onPress={this.changePwdType}
                />
            { control.isTouched &&
              control.isInvalid && 
              <View>
                { control.errors.pattern ?
                  <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>Dein Passwort muss mindestens 8 Zeichen lang sein und mindestens ein Sonderzeichen oder eine Zahl enthalten.</Text> : 
                  <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>Bitte trage dein Passwort ein.</Text> }
              </View> }
          </View>
        ) }
      </Foect.Control>

<Foect.Control name="confirmpassword">
        { control => (
          <View>
            <Text style={{ marginTop: 10, color: '#8BC051' }}>Passwort wiederholen
            </Text>

            <TextInput
              style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderBottomWidth: 1}}
              secureTextEntry={true}
              onBlur={control.markAsTouched}
              onChangeText={(text) => control.onChange(text)}
              value={control.value}
              placeholder="Passwort bitte wiederholen"
            />
          </View>
        ) }
      </Foect.Control>
    </View>
  ) }
</Foect.Form>
          
            <View style={{marginTop: 10}}>
            <Button full warning style={styles.buttonintervall} onPress={
            () => navigate("Ziel", {})}>>>
            <Text>Registrieren</Text>
            </Button>
            </View>

            <Text style={styles.secondtextfb}> oder </Text>
            
          <Card>
          <CardItem>

            <Icon name="logo-facebook" style={{color: '#234c6e'}} />
            <Text>Über Facebook registrieren</Text>
            <Right>
            <Icon name="arrow-forward" />
            </Right>

          </CardItem>
          </Card> 
           
        </Content>
        </Container>
        
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is native-base really involved here?

Comment: Um yes, the Header and the Facebook Login are from Native Base!

Comment: Facebook login is not by NativeBase

Comment: I mean just the Carditem and Card function from the Facebook Button/Login!!!! this is native base. but this is not my question so i don't understand your problem!